# Authentication Service object is lost page on refresh in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the mean.js boilerplate, which has authentication built in. However, I'm having a problem using the boilerplate Authentication Serivce.

Here is the service:

```
'use strict';

// Authentication service for user variables
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', [


    function() {
        var _this = this;
        var _user_exists = {};

        _this._data = {
            user: window.user
        };
        return _this;
    }
]);
```

Now in the Authentication controllers when I sign in I have the following snippet:

```
$http.post('/auth/signin', $scope.credentials).success(function(response) {
                // If successful we assign the response to the global user model
                $scope.authentication.user = response;
```

Which is great - as there is now a user object within $scope.authentication that contains the user data. This then customises the  the header view that has the customised navbar (with user data from $scope.authentication.user).

However, I'm using HTML5, and every time i refresh the page it seems that the user object is overwritten and becomes empty - which seems as thought the user has been logged out (on the nav bar).

However I can still see all of the user data if I do `'console.log($scope.authentication._data.user);'`

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: could you please elaborate - i'm a bit of a noob

Comment: use ngStorage or ngCookie to store your current user and, before doing a /auth, check your cookie or localStorage

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate, my comment, you need persistant date into your browser.

This can be easily performed with localStorage or Cookies. (ngCookies or ngStorage)

When user authenticated, store the datas to the approriate persistent storage.

When user start your app (.run()) or at the begining of your controller, check your persistent storage to retreive the user information if user has already been authenticated.

Comment: at the moment I have the lots of the following: data-ng-if="menu.shouldRender(authentication.user);"> in my navbar, which evaluates to true is the Authentication service returns true - are you saying every page refresh will remove the value of $scope.authentication.user, and that I need to use the cookie instead?

Comment: if so would i just adjuest the data-ng-if="menu.shouldRender(authentication.user);"> to be something like data-ng-if="menu.shouldRender(cookie.user);">

Comment: On your authentication service, before doing your request to your Authentication service, check your persistant storage (cookies or localStorage). If there is datas, then user has already been authenticated and fill in authentication.user with your storage datas, if not, then request for authentication

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very useful object for storing data in Local Storage:

```
var LocalStorageManager = {
    setValue: function(key, value) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    },
    getValue: function(key) {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
        } catch (e) {

        }
    }
};
```

To store data:

```
LocalStorageManager.setValue("key",data);
```

To retrieve data:

```
LocalStorageManager.getValue("key");
```